# Press Enter on URL in address bar with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am running a script with `Selenium` that loops over a number of URLs. However, some URLs give a `503 service error`.  For example the following code gives me such an error.

```
import requests 
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://destyy.com/q3P5W7' 
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
response = requests.get(driver.current_url).status_code
```

I tried refreshing the browser in the case of an error, but then the error persists.

```
if response == 503:
   driver.refresh()
```

I noticed that if I manually select the url in the address bar of my driver and press enter, the page loads to the desired location. I tried to write this into code but it fails:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

address_bar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "l")
address_bar.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Please help me out. How can I load the page? Thanks in advance,

Comment: How about `driver.navigate().go_to_url(url)`?

Comment: Because service unavailable. Try the url in the browser.

Comment: I get an error  `using driver.navigate`. AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'navigate'

Comment: When I try the URL in the browser by re-entering it, it works and gets redirected to the correct page. How to do this within my script?

Comment: you might try setting PageLoadStrategy to "none".  The options vary by driver (some take a string some take enum constant): https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/PageLoadStrategy.html  OR, maybe go directly to whatever page it's redirecting to?

Comment: Try adding parentheses after navigate - it is a function not a property.

Comment: Sorry, I tried `driver.navigate().go_to_url(url)` and it didn't work